# Trouble resolving a promise

Tags: javascript, promise

I'm trying to resolve a promise via await, so I can continue without a huge nested clusterF.

```
var getPort = require('get-port');

var get_port = async function(){
  var port_promise = new Promise((resolve_port) => {
    getPort({port: 16100}).then(resolve_port);
  });

  var port = await port_promise;
  return port;
};

var port = get_port();
```

However, this code throws an error on

```
server.listen(port);
```

saying the value is a promise instead of a number. I thought the await took care of that.

Comment: Did you try 
  var port = await port_promise(); ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Async functions return a **Promise object** that will eventually be resolved by a return value supplied when executing the function body - either by executing a return statement or by executing the last statement in the body and returning `undefined`.

Async functions **do not** wait for asynchronous operations inside the `async` function to complete.
This is so the code calling the async function can complete and return to the event loop - thereby allowing any outstanding or newly initiated asynchronous operations to proceed.

The `await` operator calls `then` on its operand promise, stores the function's execution context, returns to the task manager, get's called back by the `then` handlers it provided, restores the saved execution context and returns the fulfilled value of its operand as the result of the `await` operation. Because of the `then` call back usage, `await` operations are *never* evaluated synchronously.

So

```
var port = get_port();
```

returns a promise to be resolved with a port number. If it is not called within an async function, use a `then` handler to pick up the port number:

```
var port = get_port();
port.then( port=> server.listen(port));
```

---

The posted code shows an antipattern of creating a promise that is always resolved or rejected by another promise - just return the other promise - and if you always return a promise from an `async` function with no `await` usage, it doesn't need to be an `async` function in the first place.

Comment: Is there a way to turn asynchronous code into synchronous code without resorting to nesting everything in then()s? My problem is that I need to call `module.exports = ` on one of the objects created with information from the promise.

Comment: You can't convert an asynchronous operation into a synchronous one using JavaScript coding techniques - it's a contradiction in terms. An API may provide a synchronous version of the same operation, that doesn't return to the caller until the operation is complete, but it's not the same thing. Promises allow specifying operations that are to be performed serially by coding each operation in a `then` callback. They replace **nesting** callback functions in outer callback back functions that don't use promises (search term: "callback hell"). Calling`module.exports` could be a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Await does not turn your Promise into synchronous code; it's just a convenient way to sequence together different bits of asynchronous code. Asynchronous functions still have to be awaited themselves or have a `.then` chained on. `get_port` is asynchronous.

```
const getPort = require('get-port');

async function startServer() {
  // Somehow get a server
  var port = await getPort({ port: 16100 });
  server.listen(port);
}

// In calling code
async function someAsyncFunc {
  await startServer();
}
// or startServer().then(() => { ... }); if you are outside of an async func
```